# Get opening times in PHP from Google My Business

Tags: php, google-my-business-api

I need a bit of PHP code to pull my opening times from my google my business listing.

This works on my local machine, but doesn't work when I push the site live live. This code stops my css rendering and doesn't load any other content.

```
<?php
  $curlURL = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=Google&query_place_id=ChIJvaUbkgRveUgROpuZ6vQkJ5M';
  $curl = curl_init($curlURL);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  $response=curl_exec( $curl );

  for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
    $day = jddayofweek($i,1);
    $start = stripos($response,'[\"'.$day.'\",')+strlen($day)+9;
    echo($day.": ".substr($response,$start,stripos($response,'\"]',$start)-$start)."<br />");
  }
?>
```

Comment: enable error reporting so u can see if u have any errors

Comment: You seem to imply you need Google to tell you when your business is open. That does sound a bit funny... Also: If Google doesn't work, for whatever reason, your website stops working? How many dependencies like that are in your website?

Comment: My website is not dependent on google. I have set up a Google my Business page and listed opening times for my business. I only want to embed the opening times I have listed on my page so when my hours of opening changes, I do not have to update the hours in google and on my website. So when I’m out and about, I can just use the google app to update my hours and not have to wait until I get home to launch my website and manually enter the details.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The given code does not involve any CSS after all

Comment: Parsing the output of maps seems very fragile, I'd suggest you to dig into the [Google My Business API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations#Location.BusinessHours) so you can parse a deterministic output.

Comment: Also, as you are echoing parts of an html string, you may want to check that the output of your function is correct by checking the production source code. You may have html fragments leaking and therefore messing with your page's HTML

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I’ve got it fixed. Apparently the date function needed to be added to my web hosting account at my providers end

Comment: Code works perfectly for me. Thanks. This is a great solution.