# Get opening hours of a business on Google Maps and treat it with PHP

Tags: php, json, maps

Do you know if there is a way to retreive opening hours of a business listed on Google Maps, and for which we have admin access, in order to treat it with PHP ?

On the website, I want to use these information in order to display something link :

- Open today : 8am to 9pm

And when the owner update specific hours (for holidays for example), the information will be automatically correctly displayed on the website :

- Closed today (Christmas Day)

Maybe we can get these informations using an API on a json file...

Any thoughts on that ?

Thanks :)

Comment: What have you done to research it yourself? [Get opening times in PHP from Google My Business](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55630957/get-opening-times-in-php-from-google-my-business) or [Is it possible to show the hours from google maps on a website, so that the website hours updates when we update google maps?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103058/is-it-possible-to-show-the-hours-from-google-maps-on-a-website-so-that-the-webs) (First one seem to not be answered, but the second one does?). Also: this is not a free coding service, show your attempt and we'll help.

Comment: Read the following also: [Are “how would I get started?” questions too broad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308745/are-how-would-i-get-started-questions-too-broad) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (look at 4., regarding *"Maybe we can get these informations using an API on a json file..."*)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I didn't knew where should I start. I don't understand how i missed the topics you found, maybe I need another coffee :) Thanks again, I'll work on that and come here once I finished